# How to setup tenant in wso2 with multi-part name

Tags: wso2

We have a use-case to setup the tenant names like impactcorp.co.uk, impactcorp.co.in etc.

When the tenant name is having more than one 'dot'( . ), the requests to the apis are failing.

Is that something achievable ?

More than one dot in the tenant name.

Comment: Are you using WSO2 Identity server? Could you please mention the product version?

Comment: Could you please explain more on the behavior of `the requests to the apis are failing.`? What is the tried API? What is the response you got?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is specific to a particular tenant, which when tested from postman looked to be a problem with spaces in the beginning and ending of the tenant name (not sure though how it got created with it in the first place). Probably a test tenant.

Thanks @Anuradha for your response.